# Photometric function Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Does anyone know how to define a photometric function in Three.js?

At the moment I'm using a Lambert

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
```

But I want to use a *Lommel Seeliger* and I don't know where and how to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom fragment shader for this purpose. You can take a look near the bottom of [this page](http://steps3d.narod.ru/tutorials/lighting-tutorial.html) for a sample implementation of a Lommel-Seeliger shader.

Within Three.js, use a [ShaderMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial) to apply your shader. A nice introduction to the concept is [this tutorial](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-1/), basically you do

```
var shaderMaterial =
  new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader:   vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I got the fragment shader but which vertex shader do I need to use for an implementation of a Lommel-Seeliger?

Comment: vertex shader: `void main(void) { gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; }`